# Removing items from the Places menu or removing the Places menu entirely

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome

I am looking to lockdown Ubuntu for an end user, the Ubuntu version and GNOME version is 3.18.1.2-1ubuntu1.16.04.2.  I have configured the applications menu to how I want, I have removed bookmarks from the Places menu, however there are a few items I cannot find how to remove.

In the places menu I would like to remove the following:-

- Home Folder
- Desktop
- Computer
- Network
- Recent Documents

Or if I can remove the Places menu entire from the top bar that would be better.

I am looking to do this via configuration, not the GUI.

Places Menu:

[image]

```
root@ubuntu:~# gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions
No such schema 'org.gnome.shell'


root@ubuntu:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: there is a search section in the settings. if you disable tracking of any sort there no pesky items will show up in places anymore.

Comment: Probably  using GNOME Flashback.

Comment: Yes I removed sections of the applications menu editing gnome-flashback-applications.menu.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Added to main question for clarity.

Comment: @Pubstars Please run `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` in Terminal. A window with GNOME extensions should appear. Please check which ones are active (if any), especially one called '*Places Status Indicator*'.

Comment: @pomsky I just ran that and got `bash: gnome-shell-extension-prefs: command not found`.  Apologies for the last response I got moved onto another project last week.

Comment: btw, I can alt+right click on places and it gives me an option to remove this from the panel.  This is what I want to do but at a configuration level for scalability.